# Get-AzAccessToken is failing with error "SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I'm attempting to gain an access token in PowerShell, to access my Funciton App which requires Azure AD authentication.

I am running the following commands:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription <subscriptionID> -TenantId <tenantID>
Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "<resourceURL>"
```

The result is the following error:
`Get-AzAccessToken : SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. Token acquisition failed for user <username>. Ensure that you have authenticated with a developer tool that supports Azure single sign on.`

I am able to access the same app via my web browser, and via Postman, but am struggling with PowerShell.

My function app is configured to return a 302 redirect for unauthenticated requests, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Function App Authentication confirugation]

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?force_isolation=true&view=azure-dotnet#examples

Comment: Thanks  @jdweng.  That's some useful background, although I'm not sure it addresses my particular issue...?  (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: You have a credential issue.  There are multiple types of credentials.  See : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/defaultazureidentity-and-its-various-credential-types3/?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in this [blog](https://azurebuild.wordpress.com/2020/09/11/acquire-azure-access-token-with-powershell/) by @vishnugillela, here is the one of the methods which we use to get access token from managed identity login with Azure AD for an Azure function app resource.

Instead of using `Get-AzAccessToken` , I used the `Invoke-WebRequest` PowerShell command to retrieve the function app resource access token.

*I tried the below PS script in my environment by providing my function app resource URL as shown and it was successfully generated the access token.*

```
$Uri = 'https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net'
 
$res = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"} -UseBasicParsing
$content = $res.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$generatedaccessToken = $content.access_token
$generatedaccessToken
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use PowerShell functions to generate the access token for a particular azure resource as given in the above referenced article. I also tried the same in my environment by making few modifications and it worked as expected.

```
function Get-AccToken {
    $con = Get-AzContext
    $profile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
    $profileClient = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient -ArgumentList ($profile)
    $tokenretrieve = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($con.Subscription.TenantId)
    return $tokenretrieval.AccessToken
}
$subscriptionid = "subscriptionID"
$authHeader = @{
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + (Get-AccToken)
}
 $url = "https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net"
 $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $authHeader -Uri $url
$response
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jahnavi for taking the time to look at my question.  Unfortunately, neither of the approaches you have suggested are working for me.

Attempting the first method, my `$res.Content` is html format, not json, so `ConvertFrom-Json` fails.

Comment: In the second method, I am able to get a token successfully, but `Invoke-RestMethod` is telling me `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

I have added a screenshot of my authentication settings in case that is helpful.

Comment: Have you enabled the system identity for the function app? @Mike

Comment: If enabled, Go to Azure role assignments and you need to give owner role to authenticate and get access token via PowerShell. You can check this [image](https://i.imgur.com/Pn1y61B.png).

Comment: What is the error from convertfrom-json command?

Comment: The error is `ConvertFrom-Json: Conversion from JSON failed with error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.`, which isn't surprising as it's trying to parse html as json.

Yes, I System assigned identity is enabled.  What scope were you thinking of assigning Owner over?

Comment: Can you go through with these links. [Github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3284), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70860338/invoke-webrequest-content-convertfrom-json-conversion-from-json-failed-with-err)

Comment: Skip giving `convertfrom-json` and try what it is giving!

Comment: Hi, Mike.. I am facing same sort of issue.. could you resolve yours?